# Populating form fields automatically from active directory in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a custom list in my SharePoint 2010 website. When I am adding a new item to a custom SharePoint 2010 list, I want to auto populate data from active directory in the respective fields (other details of the user) when I enter the exact user Id in the first field and I will also like to send the field content as an email. - I understand that I can do this easily with MS Infopath, however my organization use the SharePoint standard edition which does not support creating forms using MS Infopath and creating a custom webpart is also not allowed by the company standard.

Can it be done through SharePoint designer or any other way besides out of the box options. Will gladly appreciate you guys help..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create either:

1. Event Receiver for the list doing all this after new item has been created, or
2. Customize the Add form using SharePoint Designer and add JavaScript code that calls some backend service when the first User Id field is filled

For 1., Event Receiver will run after user has saved the form, so user will not see the fetched details when filling in the form. This is 100% C# code, and you can search the net on how to create SharePoint list event handlers, including samples.

For 2., you will need to implement e.g., a web service that you can implement with pretty much any way you like, but key thing is that you call it using the JavaScript that you add to the New Item form using SharePoint Designer (bind it to change event of the User Id field), and sends User Id as a parameter to the web service. Web Service fetches the other user details from AD and returns those back to the JavaScript. JavaScript will will finally populate the other fields based on the returned values.

On both, you can send the email from the server side code, so either in the Event Receiver, or on the Web Service.

Comment: Thanks Jussi. The first option might not solve my problem since I will like the user to see the fetched details before the form is submitted.
The second option looks much better, however am new to SharePoint and have no idea how the web service work in this case.